# How to list all sequences by psql with postgres?

Tags: postgresql, psql, sequence

I tried `\ds` didn't get any relations data.

But I use `SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences;` can get all the data.

Why doesn't `\ds` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\ds` without argument doesn't show sequences that are not accessible through the current `search_path`, whereas `information_schema.sequences` ignores the search path.

On the other hand, `information_schema.sequences` won't show sequences that the current user cannot actually use, whereas `\ds` won't filter those out. According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-sequences.html):

> Only those sequences are shown that the current user has access to (by
> way of being the owner or having some privilege).

To see all sequences in psql, try:

```
\ds *.*
```